# Add space around React Native Image

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to increase the size of an Image "canvas" to add space around it? (The opposite of crop)

I'm drawing some SVG lines around an image. If you wrap the SVG tag inside the Image tag as follows then the SVG graphics must lie within the Image boundaries:

```
<Image source=... style={{height: 48, width:48}}>
    <Svg height="48" width="48">
        <Svg.Line ... />
    </Svg>
</Image>
```

You can make the SVG draw outside of the Image boundaries by using Gimp or similar to resize the image with whitespace around the main content. But is it possible to do this without creating new images, to get RN to add space around the image so that I can draw SVG on that whitespace?

Adding padding/margin to the image container didn't work.

Or is there a better way of doing this? I tried wrapping the Image in the SVG tag but didn't get consistent results between Android and iOS.

Comment: You can try using resizeMode property and check if that helps

Comment: @Embedded Android Did you find any solution?